# jQuery disable one checkbox when another is selected

Tags: jquery, checkbox, onchange

I have 2 checkboxes labelled keys and acoustic guitar. When a user selects one, I want the other to be disabled. I have been able to acheive this, however, the issue I'm having is that when the user unchecks their choice - the other still remains disabled.

For example, if the user selects 'keys', 'acoustic guitar' disables, if the user then un-checks 'keys', 'acoustic guitar' still stays disabled - I need it so that when none are checked, you can select either at any time.

Here is my code:

```
// disable acoustic guitar when keys is selected
$("input[class='checkbox keys']").on('change', function () {
    if ($("input[class='checkbox keys']").length) {
        $("input[class='checkbox acou_guit']").prop('disabled',true);
        return;
    } else {
        $("input[class='checkbox acou_guit']").prop('disabled',false);
        return;
    }
});

// disable keys when acoustic guitar is selected
$("input[class='checkbox acou_guit']").on('change', function () {
    if($("input[class='checkbox acou_guit']").length) {
        $("input[class='checkbox keys']").prop('disabled',true);
        return;
    } else {
        $("input[class='checkbox keys']").prop('disabled',false);
        return;
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you considered using radio buttons instead of checkboxes?

Comment: Agreed, Radio boxes make much more sense, as at any point you're selecting just one option.

Comment: And by the way, you don't need `return;` statements in *this particular example*. Saves you 4 LOC.

Comment: Thanks guys, I thought of radio boxes, but this form changes dependant on other options, for example, if a user selects a different package, they are able to select several more instruments at once. Is there a way to achieve what I need with checkboxes?

Answer (score 1):

You are likely running into weird behavior by using the `length` property. It is recommended to use `prop` instead:

Instead of:

```
if($("input[class='checkbox acou_guit']").length) { }
```

Try:

```
if($(this).prop("checked")) { }
```

This probably won't solve your issue by copy-and-paste. It should, however, send you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You're code is wrong in this case. you should check the length of the selected checkbox, not just the checkbox.

```
$("input[class='keys']").on('change', function () {
    var checked = $("input[class='keys']:checked").length === 1 ? true : false;
        $("input[class='acou_guit']").prop('disabled',checked);

});

// disable keys when acoustic guitar is selected
$("input[class='acou_guit']").on('change', function () {
    var checked = $("input[class='acou_guit']:checked").length === 1 ? true : false;
        $("input[class='keys']").prop('disabled',checked);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FL47b/

Please mark the answer as correct if it helps you